# puppet: installing a package if *another* package isn't installed

Tags: puppet

After the oracle license change, we're moving to OpenJDK on our raspberries. That is, only on the ones we're outfitting now. According to the oracle license already in-use licenses stay valid, so we don't *have* to remove the oracle jdk from our existing devices. And, sticking to the directive "never touch a running system" (much less a hundred of them), we rather wouldn't.

However, I can't seem to get puppet to only install the openjdk package if the oracle package isn't installed already. As there are no according attributes in the package resource, I tried to facilitate something with a mock exec, like so:

```
  exec { 'checking java installation':
    command => '/bin/echo no existing java installation found',
    creates => '/usr/bin/java'
  }
  ~> package { 'java':
    name => 'openjdk-8-jdk',
  }
```

The idea is that the exec doesn't execute because a link to a java executable already exists, and the chained package resource therefore doesn't refresh.

However, while the exec doesn't execute, the package resource still does. I also tried subscribing instead (which should basically be the same thing if I understood that correctly), same result.

So how do I prevent the package resource from running?

Comment: The `package` resource is not refreshable. You can achieve your goal with a custom fact to check the existence of java on the system. Conveniently, there are a number of answers already in SO on how to check for the existence of something on a system with a custom fact and then apply a resource given that, so do a quick seach and you should find plenty of assistance.

Comment: What Matt said.  Additionally, note that `~>` and `notifies` do not in any case express that the target resource is *applied* only if it receives an event.  They express that it is *refreshed* only if it receives an event (whether that has any effect for the resource type or not).  That the resource is declared at all expresses that it should be applied.